# PHP choose a word from a string

Tags: php, string, strpos

in the string XX is always changed and string can be longer or shorter and it can be without searched word, where XX is a number 
example:

```
1 kom. nije naručeno, obično dolazi za 5 dana., slični: sony-6am6ptb1a (0 kom.), sony-s006pb1a (-9 kom.)
```

So from that I need to output just: obično dolazi za 5 dana

So how can I chose just &find in any case?

```
$find = "obično dolazi za XX dana.";

$string ="1 kom. nije naručeno, obično dolazi za XX dana.";

if (strpos($string,$find) !== false) {
  echo '$string contains $find';
}
```

I think this is it:

```
$string = "1 kom. nije naručeno, obično dolazi za XX dana.";

for(int intIndex = 1; intIndex <= 31; intIndex++)
{
 $find = "obično dolazi za " . strval(intIndex) . " dana."

 if (strpos($string,$find)) 
 {
 echo '$string contains $find';
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're asking, please re-state your question.

Comment: why are you asking? Your code would work... or I've misunderstood the question

Comment: [`mb_stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-stripos.php)

Comment: He's trying to locate the position of an unknown. I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the 'search string' has a portion (`XX`) that changes and you don't necessarily know what it will be in a given situation. So you can't use `strpos` because of the unknown segment.

You'll have to use a regular expression based on the left and right parts of the search string.

Please see [PHP Manual: preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for more details.

Without knowing what `XX' represents I can't offer anything more.

Or...

If you want to return the `XX` and the left-most and right-most parts are constant...

```
// given '1 kom. nije naručeno, obično dolazi za XX dana.'

$string = str_replace("1 kom. nije naručeno, obično dolazi za ", "", str_replace(" dana.", "", $string));
// $string now contains the value of 'XX'

print $string;
```

Output is `XX`.

Or...

Is this good enough for your needs..? [*It is based on what you came up with! :)*]

```
<?php
    // just throwing '23' in there to demonstrate the awesome power!
    $string = "1 kom. nije naručeno, obično dolazi za 23 dana.";
    for ($intIndex = 1; $intIndex <= 31; $intIndex++) {
        $find = "1 kom. nije naručeno, obično dolazi za " . strval($intIndex) . " dana.";

        // we test that it's not 'false', because it could be '0'
        if (strpos($string, $find) !== false) {
            echo "$string contains $find";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: XX is number of days and I dont know what will be

Comment: Are you trying to return the number of days?

Comment: I think this is it


$string = "1 kom. nije naručeno, obično dolazi za XX dana.";

for(int intIndex = 1; intIndex <= 31; intIndex++)
{
 $find = "obično dolazi za " . strval(intIndex) . " dana."
 
 if (strpos($string,$find)) 
 {
  echo '$string contains $find';
 }
}

Comment: @mehnihma The working code would be something like... `<?php

$string = "1 kom. nije naručeno, obično dolazi za 23 dana.";for ($intIndex = 1; $intIndex <= 31; $intIndex++) {        $find = "1 kom. nije naručeno, obično dolazi za " . strval($intIndex) . " dana.";
        if (strpos($string,$find) !== false) {
                echo "$string contains $find";
        }
} 

?>`

Answer (score 0):

I want to guess you have issues with the output ... and its returning

```
 $string contains $find
```

Use `"` instead of `'`

```
$find = "obično dolazi za XX dana.";
$string ="1 kom. nije naručeno, obično dolazi za XX dana.";
if (mb_stripos($string,$find) !== false) {
  echo "$string contains $find";
}
```

Output

```
 1 kom. nije naruÄeno, obiÄno dolazi za XX dana. contains obiÄno dolazi za XX dana.
```

Comment: Yes something like that, XX is just a number , number of days in this case
I just need to chose that specific part of the string

Comment: Really i don't understand what you really want to achive